# Retrigger css animation using Angular

Tags: css, angular

I have a simple HTML list I use to mimic slot machine animation:

```
  <ul class="digits slot" #digits>
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>{{ counter }}</li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.digits {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  margin-top: 0em;
}

.digits {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.slot {
  animation-name: slot;
}

/* Animations */
@keyframes slot {
  100% {
    margin-top: -7em;
  }
}
```

so far nothing too fancy. Problem is I want to prevent the animation from taking place on initial load. `counter` changes during session and only then I want to apply the animation. My solution was to set initial duration to 0 -> `animation-duration: 0s;` and using the `ngAfterViewInit` hook to apply the new css.

```
this.element.nativeElement.style.animationDuration = '3s';
```

problem is I cant seem to test this solution since when creating a button to shange the value of `counter` doesnt apply animation. Any idea why and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could always remove the `.slot` class and add it on click as an alternative and easier method.

Is that all the JavaScript you are using though?
If so, and you want to stick with what you have, you might want to change it to this;

`document.getElementsByClassName("digits")[0].style.animationDuration = "3s";`

Otherwise please provide more of your JavaScript so we can better assist with why your code isn't working as intended.